# Add Data to a Table from UserForm in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

im trying to add data from a Userform into an Excel Table. It's a really easy procedure but i got some Problems.
`

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim test As String

test = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Name
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = test
ActiveSheet.ListObjects.ListRows.Add
'Dim LastRow As Long
'Dim Header As Integer
'Dim Column As Integer

'With ActiveSheet.ListObject(Table1)
'    LastRow = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(Table1).ListRows.Count
'
'    If .Sort.Header = xlYes Then
'        iHeader = 1
'    Else
'        iHeader = 0
'    End If
'End With
'ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = TextBox1.Value
End Sub
```

The commented part is the thing i tried to do. But VBA says that it doesnt find the method.

Comment: Welcome to SO, could you be more specific about the error, what is the error text exactly?

Comment: If your table is named `Table1` then `ListObjects("Table1")` (notice the quotes) would fix it. Otherwise VBA is parsing `Table1` as a token, and with `Option Explicit` that token resolves to an undeclared variable, which results in a compiler error.

Comment: Hi thank you for the quick answer.
It says RUntime ERror 438.
I added manually a table to the Excel Sheet and called it Table 1. I added some pseudo values to test it. 
First thing is I want to make a Simple Bookkeeping UserForm. On Userform1 i have 3 buttons. Money Output, Input and Permanent Output. The Input Button opens Userform2 where i can add a Value which should be added to a table in this case table 1. Thats all.
If i try to start, it cant find the methods for the 'ActiveSheet.ListObjects(Table1).ListRows.Count'

Comment: `Table1` needs to be in quotes, it's a `String` literal.

Comment: Also, if `Table1` isn't in the `ActiveSheet`, your code breaks

Comment: Hi, got it. THank you